# Unable to connect to Python on my own computer in Power BI

Tags: python, powerbi, anaconda, powerbi-desktop

I'm attempting to figure out the mechanics of running Python scripts in Power BI for Reasons and I've hit a snag. I was running through the steps in this [somewhat basic tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts) and I came to the section in which I am supposed to paste the script into they Python Script screen, which is Step 3 of the 'Run the Script and Import Data' section.

When I followed the steps, which are essentially to paste the example script into the window and hit Okay, I got this 'helpful' error:

`

```
Details: "ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my.username\PythonScriptWrapper_aca634c7-30c3-4bf4-881b-d1e47bb0a919\PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\my.username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\my.username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\my.username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\my.username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
</pi>"
```

`

I have verified that the matplotlib and pandas packages were installed via pip list, os doesn't show up, which surprised me but I know it's part of the standard library so I'm not stressing about it unless someone thinks I should. Is anyone an expert in this? Is there a better way? Am I doomed to scream into the Power BI void for all eternity?

Answer (score 1):

The **somewhat basic tutorial** is based on using standard python from python.org. However, you are using the Anaconda distribution, which basically requires the environment to be activated before any modules - especially pandas' C-library - can be accessed.

You can achieve that in the **cmd** shell by running

```
conda activate
C:\Users\my.username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PBIDesktopStore.exe
```

which assumes that you are using the Power BI Desktop version from the Microsoft store.

Comment: PBIDesktopStore is an "windows store app alias", so it's always in the user's path and can be launched from any folder.